# Convert unix timestamp to normal Date in Json

Tags: ajax, json, date, laravel-5, unix-timestamp

I am using laravel 5.0. I am getting data from controller as json. I am having value like this.

```
{"timstamp_date":"1434360957"},
```

I need to convert this unix timestamp value as Normal Date Like `(15-06-2015)` or `(15-March-2015)`.

I have used `Date(timstamp_date)` but it is showing current time only. Not my timstamp date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you doing this in the controller in php or after you have sent it from the controller in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
date("d-m-Y H:i:s", 1434360957);
```

EDIT
You could try;

```
var dateTime = new Date(1434360957*1000);
var formatted = dateTime.toGMTString();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sp57Lnpf/

Comment: I thought you are using PHP. Are you using javascript?

Comment: Yes I am using javascript

Comment: I need to convert my value as Normal Date using javascript

Comment: I edit my answer. Is that what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use the date function. You need to specify the format as the first parameter:

```
date("d-m-Y", $timestamp_date)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Laravel also comes with Carbon you could use that if you wanted to for further manipulation of the data if you so required it.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I am not using php I just want to convert timstamp in Json

Comment: You're using javascript then?

Comment: If yes, look at wonderb0lt's comment in your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript or you could check out a library like moment.js if you're doing a lot of date manipulation